# Excel: How to convert abbreviations for thousands (k) and millions ($m) into numeric values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to convert abbreviations for thousands (k) and millions ($m) into numeric values - how do I do that in Excel? (see also the example attached). Have to admit I am not an advanced user and the other posts on that topic didn't work and showed an error message.

- First column shows abbreviations in thousands(k) and millions (m) - is there a formula which I can apply for the entire column?
- Second column shows abbreviations with millions and a dollar sign - would like to remove both and only have a numeric value (e.g "$34k" into "34.000")

[image: example table]

Comment: I found this on another StackExchange: https://superuser.com/questions/1459247/how-to-convert-1k-to-1000-and-1m-to-1000000-in-excel/1459249

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution**

For column H:

```
=IFNA(LEFT(H2,LEN(H2)-1)*CHOOSE(MATCH(RIGHT(H2,1),{"k","m"},0),1000,1000000),H2)
```

For column I:
(almost the same, but remove the first character "$")

```
=IFNA(MID(I2,2,LEN(I2)-2)*CHOOSE(MATCH(RIGHT(I2,1),{"k","m"},0),1000,1000000),I2)
```

**The explanation**

`LEFT`: extracts the leftmost characters from your string (the number) used for column H

`MID`: extracts the middle characters from your string (the number) used for column I

`RIGHT`: extracts 1 rightmost character from your string (the letter)

`MATCH`: tells you if that character is "k" or "m"

`CHOOSE`: if the character is "k" multiply number by 1000, if the character is "m" multiply number by 1000000

`IFNA`: used to check for errors; if the result is not a number, return the original content of the cell (for example if you had a number with no "k" or "m" suffix)

**If this doesn't work for you**

Please provide which formula(s) you tried and the error message you received. It's difficult to provide additional help otherwise. It could be a problem with locale (such as needing to use semicolons (;) instead of commas (,) in the formula.

Comment: Thank you so much for the formula and underlying explanation, it worked!

Comment: If this worked for you, consider marking the answer as "accepted" and vote it up so it can be helpful to others. See the [site guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)